# Nested each do loops printing unexpectedly in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, nested-loops

I have two arrays containing strings. I'm trying to iterate through both arrays with nested .each do loops to see if any elements in the first array have a substring of any of the elements in the second array. I'm using .include? within the nested loops to check this. I want the result to be the string printed the number of times it matches an element in partials.

This is the method that isn't working

```
def orphanCheck(partials, partials1, duplicatesArray)
  partials1.each do |i|
    partials.each do |j|
      if i.include?(j)
        duplicatesArray.push(i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using this as a helper method to define partials and partials1

```
def manipulate(monthEmails, todayEmails, partials, partials1)
  monthEmails.each do |i|
    email = EmailAddress.new(i.to_s)
    partials.push(email.host_name.to_s)
  end
  todayEmails.each do |j|
    todaySignup = j.to_s.slice(11, 100)
    partials1.push(todaySignup)
  end
end
```

And then I'm calling the two with the following

```
manipulate(allUnique, todayEmails, partials, partials1)

orphanCheck(partials, partials1, duplicatesArray)
#puts duplicatesArray
```

duplicatesArray is printing some strings that shouldn't be matches and it's printing some strings more times than I want. For example, gmail.com isn't in partials at all but me@gmail.com, which is in partials1 once, is being pushed to duplicatesArray three times. If yahoo.com is in partials three times, then I would want me@yahoo.com (from partials1) to be pushed to duplicatesArray three times, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure you could be doing:

```
  partials1.each do |i|
    i_ups=i.split('@')[-1]
    partials.each do |j|
      if i_ups===j
        duplicatesArray.push(i)
        break
      end
    end
  end
```

If I understood correctly (partials is only the host part of the email provider and partials1 is the full email address)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution that should give you a correct duplicatesArray would be:

```
partials1.each do |email_address|
  email_host = email_address.split("@").last
  duplicatesArray.push(email_address) if partials.include?(email_host)
end
```